# How to float side nav along the page

Tags: css, angular

I want the side navigation to be floated left along whenever I go down the page. I was trying to implement it using sticky property. But it was not working.
See the code for your reference

```
.sticky-class {
  position: sticky;
  top: 30px;
}
```

My html snapshot is

```
<div class="side-nav" fxFlex="80" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="1px">
    <div fxFlex="15">
      <div class="sticky-class">
        <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
      </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

`app-sidenav` component is using angular material to display the content. I want it to be floated when I scroll.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: If I read it correctly, you want the `nav` to be on the left side of the bar and stay there. You can accomplish this by putting the bar on the left with the CSS `float: left;`.

Comment: I want the nav bar to be there If I scroll down also. I want it be always. It should satay in a position after scrolling little bit down.

Comment: I suggest using `position: fixed;`. This makes the nav bar stay even when you scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, you want the nav to be on the left side of the bar and appear when scrolling. You can use JavaScript to do so:

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    nav.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    nav.style.display = "block";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
};
```

```css
#nav {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  display: none;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50%;
  width: 30%;
}
#home {
  margin-top: 75%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<p>A p element!</p>
<h1>An h1!</h1>
<h2>Hurray! h2 time!</h2>
<h3>h3...yay!</h3>
<h4>Awesome!</h4>
<h5>So small...</h5>
<h6>I'm tiny!</h6>
<br>
<div>I'm a div!</div>
<span>I'm a span!</span>
<img src=""> this is an img!
<nav id="nav">
  <button id="home">Home</button>
</nav>
```

Comment: `position: fixed;` will make the element to be fixed to the screen always. But he needs it after scrolling little bit. So it won't work.